# DiscordBot Sends a welcome DM to those who have selected a certain role

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to code my bot to DM new joiners who have selected an Advertising role but It doesn't seem to be working and can't figure out why, I'm quite new to this

```
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({
    intents: [
        GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessageReactions,
        // ...
    ]
});


client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
    const advertiserRoleId = '1138502484210495648'; 

    // Check if the new member has the 'Advertiser' role
    const hasAdvertiserRole = member.roles.cache.some(role => role.id === advertiserRoleId);

    if (hasAdvertiserRole) {
        // Send a welcome DM to the new member
        member.send("Welcome to the server! Thank you for selecting the 'Advertiser' role.");
    }
});

client.login('TOKEN');
```

if anyone knows what I'm doing wrong That would be much appreciated

When new members join they are able to select an 'Advertiser' Role, I wanted the DM to send them a private DM message

(It won't be the Dm in the code above, I havn't wrote it yet, I'm just using that as a tester until I can get it to work)

Comment: `guildMemberAdd` fires when a user joins a server. I don't think they will have the advertiser role at that time. You probably want to use the `guildMemberUpdate` event.

Comment: It worked! Thank youu! 
I actually thought that myself as they select it from the Onboarding screen and not auto-assign when joined and he told me the slight delay wouldn't affect it..  Zsolt Meszaros 1 - AI 0

Ty again!

Answer (score 1):

As Zsolt already commented, `guildMemberAdd` event is fired at the moment user joins the guild.

In your case you would want to check with `guildMemberUpdate` something like:

```js
client.on('guildMemberUpdate', (oldUser, newUser) => {
    const advertiserRoleId = '1138502484210495648'; 

    // Check if the new member has the 'Advertiser' role
    const hasAdvertiserRole = newUser.roles.cache.find(role => role.id === advertiserRoleId);
    // Check if the user had the role before to avoid duplicate message.
    const hadAdvertiserRole = oldUser.roles.cache.find(role => role.id === advertiserRoleId);

    if (hasAdvertiserRole && !hadAdvertiserRole) {
        // Send a welcome DM to the new member
        member.send({content: "Welcome to the server! Thank you for selecting the 'Advertiser' role."});
    }
});
```

In above code we also check if the user **HAD** the role before, to avoid duplicate DMs.

*You might need to edit the above code to fit your needs.*